# Python - how to get log append content

Tags: python

I use watchdog to watch a log for changes,but I can't get append content from watchdog Api Reference.Is there other ways to achieve this?

```
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
import time
import os

class MyHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_modified(self, event):
        if event.src_path == ".\\test.log":
            # how to get append content from the log

if __name__ == "__main__":
    event_handler = MyHandler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path='.', recursive=False)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
```

Comment: log file is normal text file so you can use standard `open()` and `read()` to get content. If you will remeber previous size of file then you can use `seek(previous_size)` to start reading in place where new content was added. I don't know if you can keep open file all time because then `read()` should always read  new content.

Comment: I checked documentation as I expected it informs you only that file was changed but it can't give you information what was changed - if text was added to file or removed - and you have to check it on your own.  If you will remeber previous size then you can compare with new size or use it with `seek()` before you use `read()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know `Watchdog` inform only if file was modified but it doesn't give infomation what was chagened and you have to check it on your own.

I see two methods to display new appended content.

---

First: keep open file and then `read()` will read only new content.

My handler gets filename as parameter to open it at start and keep it open all time.

In `__init__` you can use `read()` to skip existing content

```
import os
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler


class AppendEventHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):

    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path
        self.fh = open(path)
        self.fh.read() # skip existing content

    def on_modified(self, event):
        if event.src_path == self.path:
            print(self.fh.read())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    event_handler = AppendEventHandler(".\\test.log")

    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, ".", recursive=True)
    observer.start()

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

---

Second: if you don't want to keep open file then you can remember its size and use it with `fh.seek(previous_size)` to start reading in place when appended content starts.

```
import os
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler


class AppendEventHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):

    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path
        self.size = os.stat(path).st_size # remeber previous size

    def on_modified(self, event):
        if event.src_path == self.path:
            new_size = os.stat(self.path).st_size # get new size 
            if new_size > self.size: 
                fh = open(self.path)
                fh.seek(self.size) # move to appended content (move to end of old content)
                print(fh.read())
                fh.close()
                self.size = new_size # remeber new size        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    event_handler = AppendEventHandler("./test.log")

    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, ".", recursive=True)
    observer.start()

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

Comment: I assumed you doesn't use rotating log which can move old content to other file and then you have to check: when new size is smaller the old size then set `self.size = 0` before you read content.